# vmware vsphere insatllation windows10

Tags: installation, vmware-vsphere

I have installed vmware esxi and I tried to install vsphere but i'm getting error "vmware vsphere requires windows server 2008 sp2 or later. vsphere cannot be insatlled on domain controller" . How to install vsphere on windows 10 to manage all VM's installed on vmware esxi

Comment: Well, you don't install vSphere. Do you mean the vSphere client?

Comment: I think he means vCenter.

Comment: OK. That would make more sense.